# Angular 2 converting json response to array and filter object in memory instead of making request each time to api

Tags: angular

I have a component with a method that does a request to the api:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    dashboardModel: any[];

    constructor(
        public dataService: DataService){
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.selectedValue = "0";
        this.dataService.setEndpoint('/api/dashboard/get');
        this.get();
    }

    private get() {
        this.dataService
            .Get()
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.dashboardModel = data;
                this.selectedData = data;
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    onSelect(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }

    onChange(selectedValue) {        
        this.selectedData = this.dashboardModel.filter(x=>x.id = selectedValue);
    }
}
```

Service is:

```
public Get = (): Observable<any[]> => {
    return this.http.get(this._apiurl, this._options).map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json());
}
```

I get data, but after I do API request I want to save data into an array in component, and then reuse this array for filtering based on dropdown select, instead of calling to api each time.

I tried to acomplish this with onChange method, but this.dashboardModel is not an array, so I get an error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.dashboardModel.filter is not a function

How do I achieve this? Since my service is generic, I cannot hardcode filtering there, it has to be in component.

Structure of this.dashboardModel says it's array:
[image]

Comment: Could you please `console.log(this.dashboardModel)` in `onChange()` and show the structure of it?

Comment: can you show a sample of your `data` obtained in the `subscribe`? Also, it doesn't make sense to assign the entire `data` to `this.selectedData` if it is meant to hold only one element of the list

Comment: @RichardMatsen I've updated with image for you. It says array. Not sure why filter doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

`x=>x.id = selectedValue`

to this:

`x => x.id === selectedValue`

And maybe just to see what it does try this:

```
onChange(selectedValue) {
    if(this.dashboadModel.length) {
       this.selectedData = 
          this.dashboardModel.find(x=>x.id === selectedValue);
    }
}
```

**Edited in light of comment and re-read of question**, since this is a drop down you are likely only selecting a single item.  So you will need remove 
`this.selectedData = data;` from the inside of your subscribe method as well.

Comment: `this.selectedData = this.dashboardModel.filter(x=> x.id === this.selectedValue)[0]` or `this.selectedData = this.dashboardModel.find(x=> x.id === this.selectedValue)`?

Comment: `.find` returns 1(first found) or undefined..  That would be most direct route..   But more importantly, in your question above you had a single `=` instead of `===` so there was assignment instead of comparison.

Comment: Is that comment for me? I'm not the OP. Was pointing out you also ommited `===` in the final block, and that your filter needed an index to return a single object. You could update your answer for clarity.

Comment: Your totally right.  Thx and edited.  Although OP's code is not clear if this.selectedData is also an [] as there is this indicating its not `this.selectedData = data;`

Comment: Yes indeed. I would expect `this.selectedData` to be single (on the basis that `this.dashboardModel` is the list), and therefore that line needs ammending as well.

Comment: this.dashboardModel is single, and this.dashboardModel.exercisesProgress is array as seen on image. The problem is that I cannot use dot notation to access array and then filter this.dashboardModel.exercisesProgress.filter()